# Unique field case insensitive constraint

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to ensure that all tags are unique when converted to lowercase. However, when I run the migrate on the following model I receive the following error:

---

```
api.Tag: (models.E012) 'constraints' refers to the nonexistent field 'Lower(F(name))'.
```

---

```
class Tag(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=30)


  class Meta:
    constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(
            fields=[Lower('name')],
            name='unique_name'
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: What Django version are you using?

Comment: UniqueConstraint is a new feature in Django 4.0

Comment: @HelgeSchneider: no, the UniqueConstraint itself exists since [tag:Django-2.2] (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint), using expressions is new in [tag:Django-4.0].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [django-4.0](/questions/tagged/django-4.0), you can work with *expressions* in a [**`UniqueConstraint`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint.expressions), so:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                Lower('name'),
                name='unique_name'
            )
        ]
```